# How to handle model migration when store them in UserDefault?

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I have an object called `User` that conforms to `Codable` introduced in Swift4.

for example, this object used to be

```
struct User: Codable {
    var firstName: String
}
```

and we use `PropertyListDecoder().decode(User.self, from: data)` and `PropertyListEncoder().encode(value)` to encode the `User` into `Data` and decode `Data` into `User`.

Now we updated the object to be

```
struct User: Codable {
    var firstName: String
    var isLoggedIn: Bool
}
```

If our app updated from the old app that has the old `Data` stored in `UserDefault`. The first thing app gonna do after update is fetch this `Data` and tries to decode into `User` by using `PropertyListDecoder().decode(User.self, from: data)`. But, it gives an error:

```
po PropertyListDecoder().decode(User.self, from: data)
▿ DecodingError
  ▿ keyNotFound : 2 elements
    - .0 : CodingKeys(stringValue: "isLoggedIn", intValue: nil)
    ▿ .1 : Context
      - codingPath : 0 elements
      - debugDescription : "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"isLoggedIn\", intValue: nil) (\"isLoggedIn\")."
      - underlyingError : nil
```

Any idea how I would handle the model migration in this case? I know that for Coredata there's some easy ways to deal with this but I have no idea how to pull it off in UserDefault.

Comment: Can you make isLoggedIn optional?

Comment: @ChrisShaw that probably wouldn't be ideal just for the sake of migration, right?

Comment: Like most things, "that depends". It's not ideal, correct. But if you add a computed property that is used by code (instead of accessing the member directly) you can handle it easily. The other option is to write your own Decoder (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types, Encode and Decode Manually).

Comment: I don't think using the `NSUserDefaults` for storage here is a good idea, `NSUserDefauls` has a limit size to archive the data within it, create a new file under the documents directory to archive it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could implement the decode initializer and set a default value for `isLoggedIn` if there isn't any:

```
struct User: Codable {
  var firstName: String
  var isLoggedIn: Bool

  enum Keys: CodingKey {
    case firstName
    case isLoggedIn
  }

  public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    firstName = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .firstName)
    isLoggedIn = try container.decodeIfPresent(Bool.self, forKey: .isLoggedIn) ?? false
  }
}
```